# Possible to run bower & npm on Travis-initiated builds?

Tags: javascript, maven, npm, bower, travis-ci

I have a project that I'm hosting at GitHub (https://github.com/njacobs5074/InOutBoard) that runs the **npm** and **bower** commands from Maven as part of the build.  This is done to ensure that the proper JavaScript packages are installed - my project is a Java web app with a JavaScript front-end.

Obviously this works fine on my dev box since I have these commands installed an in my PATH.  Just not clear on how to get this working with Travis.

Thanks much,

Nick

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every Travis [worker](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Runtimes) has a node.js runtime and NPM installed, so you can use it to install Bower.
In order to install Bower and run bower install add the following to .travis.yml:

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g bower
  - bower install
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped.  I had to do a bit more than that because I want npm & bower to run via Maven when working on it locally - so I used a Maven profile based on the directory that gets created by bower.  But, thanks again.