# Not able to run bower on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, bower, travis-ci

I have almost tried every possible thing here, but am not able to run builds on Travis CI as it errors out on bower.

I know this question might sound like a duplicate, but I have tried the usual fix that seems to be working for everyone else, but not for me :)
An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29064091/1749585

My repository is https://github.com/myTerminal/faded-multiselect and you can find it on Travis CI at https://travis-ci.org/myTerminal/faded-multiselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing bower in `before_install` rather than `before_script`. Your `.travis.yml` would look like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.11"
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli bower
  - bower install
sudo: required
```

The way Node.js applications are built on Travis CI is that is executes `before_script` after `install` (which does `npm install`), `before_script` is something that is executed after the `install` step.

You need `bower` during your `npm install`, hence your build fails.

Comment: Thanks, approved your pull-request